# Freeze PyGObject applications on Windows

Tags: python, gtk, cx-freeze, pygobject

I am currently using PyGObject to create a simple GTK+ application. I am mostly focusing on GNU/Linux but I would like to make it available on Windows too. It seems that the only way to run it would be using MSYS2 MinGW on Windows and install the libraries there. I also saw a setup.py for cx_Freeze that i managed to use, but cx_Freeze does not have a single file option and I would like to have a portable executable that bundles all the dependencies. I used PyInstaller successfully out of the box on my Arch system and is there a way to use it on MinGW too? Or, what other options do I have to freeze and bundle this application?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you already have a working solution to freeze your application with `cx_Freeze` and your actual question is:

**How to create a portable executable that bundles all the dependencies with cx_Freeze?**

`cx_Freeze` itself does not support building a single file exe, where all of the libraries for your application are embedded in one executable file, but you have several options to create a single-file **installer** allowing you to make the application available on Windows:

1. You can use tools to compress the build directory from `cx_Freeze` into a self-extracting archive, see the [corresponding FAQ in the cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables).
2. You can let `cx_Freeze` build a simple installer containing all the files `cx_Freeze` includes for your application, by running the setup script as:

   ```
   python build.py bdist_msi
   ```

   See the [corresponding section of the cx_Freeze documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script).
3. In order to make a more customizable installer, you can use script-based tools such as [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and run the installer-generating script after the `cx_Freeze` setup script.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use Msys2 to bundle a PyGObject app in Windows with PyInstaller.
This person has an SDK that you can set up to make the build in a sandbox.

https://github.com/exaile/python-gtk3-gst-sdk/tree/master/win_installer

I haven't used it myself, but one of the maintainers of PyInstaller recommends it.